# EasyAdmin: in configureFields, how can I invoke an entity method (not available directly in its Dto)?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

In an application based on Symfony 6 and EasyAdmin 4, I'm working on the `configureFields` of a CrudController.

On the Crud index page, I need to show an `url` field whose value depends on some logic which resides in the related Entity.

This is my 'configureFields` method:

```php
yield TextField::new("url")
  ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/download-link.html.twig')
  ->hideOnForm();
```

This is the Twig template `admin/field/download-link.html.twig`:

```php
<a href="{{ entity.Fullpath }}">
    {% if entity.DownloadableExists %}Download{% else %} FILE ERROR{% endif %}
</a>
```

The problem is: in the Twig template, `entity.DownloadableExists` (which contains my custom logic) doesn't exist because `entity` is an instance of `EntityDto` istead of being my real entity.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that `entity.instance` exists. It give access to the entity, so the solution was just easy as `entity.instance.DownloadableExists`.